# How to efficiently get a entry with highest version in mysql table

Tags: mysql

I need to get an entry from mysql with a given id but the version should be maximum.

I have a table of entries. All entries have id and version( these two are the composite keys of the table). I need to get all entries with unique id and max version.. How do I do it efficiently. 
1. do I read all and pick the max for each id.
2. do i create a column with name is_latest, index on it and set it to true when new entry is put while updating older entries to false.
3. something else. :)

This should be noted that most of the calls will be read(>99%).

let the table have n entries with id 1 and versions from 1 to n

```
id  version  name  ...
1   1        abcd  ...
1   2        abcd  ...
1   3        defg  ...
```

I would like to get the last entry

```
1   3        defg  ...
```

Answer (score 2):

In mysql you could use order by and limit 1 for a single id

```
select  * 
from my_table  
order by  version desc 
limit 1
```

of for several id
use inner join  for max

```
select * 
from my_table m 
inner join (
  select  id, max(version) max_ver 
  from my_table 
  group by id 
  ) t  on t.max_ver  = m.version  and t.id = m.id
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. however joins are costly and I am just trying to avoid this.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for the `MAX()` function.

```
SELECT MAX(version) from my_table where id = your_id
```

You can have more information here : https://sql.sh/fonctions/agregation/max (French website)

Example here : https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/tJHG1JT6RJLGJJoamYHXzQ/1

Answer (score 0):

See this db-fiddle: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wMxb7S5tCGVA8gsXLHUHS3/0

```
SELECT t2.id, t2.version, t1.name
FROM my_table t1
JOIN (
    SELECT id, max(version) version FROM my_table GROUP BY id
) t2 ON t1.id = t2.id AND t1.version = t2.version
```